# react-native refresh android screen error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

New to react-native.

Created a new project using "react-native init projectName"

After setting up Android studio and emulator, made changes to the index.js file to display text.

After running the app using "react-native run-android", the emulator open the app correctly. But on double tapping R (reloading) red screen appears as attached.[image: error screen]

Sometimes a different error also occurs - Module HMRClinet is not a registered callable module(calling enable).

Need some input to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there's a few possible solutions for this( I had a similar problem )

**Gradle clean and build**

Navigate to your react native project folder in Terminal/ Command Prompt

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

And try running your project again

**Restart adb and npm servers**

Shut your npm server( the JS server which should have started when you use run-android)

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then simply try react-native run-android again

**Alternative Option**

While this is probably not the problem you can still try it.

Open Android studio.

Tools > Android > AVD Manager

Look for your emulator in the list and click the arrow next to the edit icon.

Wipe data

Try again.

Comment: I tried both the solutions and it never worked. Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: Is the problem only coming on refreshing the app?

Comment: The issue appears when i load, open or refresh. I have changed to MAC and everything is good now. But still why was it not working on windows. Should be a dependency issue i failed to install.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue in Ubuntu 16.04. In my case the problem was that node packager wasn't running.

To check is packager is running easily you can open the browser and enter

http://localhost:8081/

You must see "React Native packager is running."

If you dont, then you can start packager from console running

react-native start

If you get an error like

" ERROR watch /your/project/path/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-ru ENOSPC"

Then run first

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

Then run react-native start again and press the letter R twice in the emulator to reload.

Answer (score 0):

@shiva just make sure you've run 
 `react-native start` in your terminal.